# Where to buy .ha domain extesion?

Tags: domains, web-hosting

Is there any website/service that I can get .ha domain extension?

Answer (score 5):

It [doesn't exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) sorry

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any website/service

Here it is: http://www.iana.org/